# MATLAB: The exact size and position of the axis box in the case of `axis equal`?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

How to know the exact size and position of the axis box (without axis labels and numbers)? For example, if I use

```
figure
contourf(x,y,u,100,'linestyle','none')
axis equal
set(gca,'position',[0.1,0.1,0.7,0.8]) %normalized units
```

The size of the axis frame/box is varyed in the case of the figure window resizing (or using `axis equal`), but the value of `get(gca,'position')` remains unchanged. For example:

```
figure
Z = peaks(20);
contourf(Z,10)
set(gca,'Units','pixels')

get(gca,'position')
axis equal 
get(gca,'position')
```

ans =

```
0.1300    0.1100    0.7750    0.8150
```

after `axis equal`, the axis box is changed, but `get(gca,'position')` gives the same coordinates:
ans =

```
0.1300    0.1100    0.7750    0.8150
```

I need these to align the colorbar to the axis box (with fixed gap between them) in the case of `axis equal`.

Comment: Your question was unclear and the following explains more easily what you fnid: `figure
Z = peaks(20);
contourf(Z,10)
set(gca,'Units','pixels')
get(gca,'position')
axis equal
get(gca,'position')`

Comment: I have added your example to my question. Is it more clear  now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `axis equal`, the axis box aspect ratio is fixed and the `Position` property is treated as a maximum size. When you resize the figure window, the axis box will remain centered in the `Position` rectangle, but in order to maintain the same aspect ratio as before, it may not take up the entire `Position` rectangle.

If you want it to take up the entire `Position` rectangle, you can call `axis equal` again. (this may depend on your MATLAB version; it worked for me in R2015b).

This is also discussed in a bit more detail [on MATLAB Central](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98731-why-are-my-subplots-not-the-same-size-when-i-resize-my-figure).

To answer your original question, it's a bit complicated. You'd have to get the plot box aspect ratio (using `pbaspect()` or the axes `PlotBoxAspectRatio` property) and figure it out:

```
ah = gca();
% Get the axes Position rectangle in units of pixels
old_units = get(ah,'Units');
set(ah,'Units','pixels');
pos = get(ah,'Position');
set(ah,'Units',old_units);
% Figure the PlotBox and axes Position aspect ratios
pos_aspectRatio = pos(3) / pos(4);
box_aspect = pbaspect(ah);
box_aspectRatio = box_aspect(1) / box_aspect(2);
if (box_aspectRatio > pos_aspectRatio)
    % PlotBox is wider than the Position rectangle
    box_height = pos(3) / box_aspectRatio;
    box_dy = (pos(4)-box_height) / 2;
    box_position = [pos(1), pos(2)+box_dy, pos(3), box_height];
else
    % PlotBox is taller than the Position rectangle
    box_width = pos(4) * box_aspectRatio;
    box_dx = (pos(3)-box_width) / 2;
    box_position = [pos(1)+box_dx, pos(2), box_width, pos(4)];
end
```

Note that this will give you the box position in pixels; if you want it in the `normalized` units that are the axes default, you'll need to normalize it:

```
fig_pos = get(get(ah,'Parent'),'Position');
box_position = box_position ./ fig_pos([3 4 3 4]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately your code does not give exact position of the axis box. Moreover it leads to negative values.

Comment: Are you using a 3-D plot? It becomes a lot more complicated in that case

Comment: I use surf with view(2). Thus it is a 2D plot.

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure why you're getting negative values. Can you post a more complete example that includes how you're generating the plot?

Comment: Sorry your code is correct. I found an error in my code.

Comment: However, it is strange that we can't get these coordinates directly from the graph without relatively cumbersome calculations.

Comment: I agree 100%. MATLAB's plotting functions can be very frustrating, and are definitely one of its weak points.