# How to obtain the bounds of the axis box in a JFrame?

Tags: java, matlab, swing

I got the answer on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39395912/matlab-the-exact-size-and-position-of-the-axis-box-in-the-case-of-axis-equal). However, to get these coordinates (size and position of the axis box in the case of `axis equal`) we need to do some relatively cumbersome calculations. However, since MATLAB graphics is based on Java, we can get access to Java properties.
I have found that if we use this in MATLAB:

```
jFrame = get(gcf,'JavaFrame');
BoxHeight = jFrame.getAxisComponent.getHeight;
BoxWidth = jFrame.getAxisComponent.getWidth;
```

we can obtain a width and height of figure windows (maybe this can be associated with the components of the axis). But they are differ from the value of `get(gcf, 'Position')` or `get(gca, 'Position')` in the case of pixel units. I'm not an expert in Java (I also unsuccessfully tried to find these properties using Altman's `findjobj`).

Thus, I have two questions:

1. Why the height and width of the figure window (maybe this is the axis box) derived from the properties of MATLAB and Java are not the same (at least, they are integers in Java and floating-point numbers in MATLAB)?

For example:

```
hf=figure('units','pixels'); ha=gca(hf);
set(ha,'units','pixels');
get(hf,'position')
get(ha,'position')
```

ans =

```
488   342   560   420
73.8000   47.2000  434.0000  342.3000`
```

whereas `BoxHeight=525`, `BoxWidth=700` and the shift is always zero (`alignmentX=0.0` and `alignmentY=0.0`).

2. How to get the exact size and position of the window axes plotted in MATLAB **using Java**?

Comment: Isn't the frame you mention relative to the figure? From the examples I have seen, the java frame components always matched the dimensions of the figure. As for the height / width of the axis (in units that are normalized relative to the figure), they should be in ha.Position, where "ha" is the corresponding axes handle. You can get exact size in pixels using Matlab, by setting ha.Units = 'pixels' and then your desired size with ha.Position = [x y width height]

Comment: What operating system are you on? On Linux, they return the same size.

Comment: Hi serigado! Many thanks for your interest. My Matlab (get(gca, 'Position')) gives floating-point numbers for pixels (set(gca, 'Units','Pixels')). I have added an example to my question.

Comment: Hi Suever! Many thanks for your interest too. It is Windows 10 64bit.

Comment: @AlexanderKorovin So do you want the size of the figure or the size of the axes?

Comment: Mainly I need to obtain the bounds of the axis box in a JFrame especially in the case of `axis equal`. In addition I found that JFrame gives coordinates non-coinciding with `get(gcf,'position')` or `get(gca,'position')`.

Comment: That is peculiar. My JFrame dimensions are always equal to the ones in get(gcf, 'Position'). Maybe instead of using axis equal, you could use a pos = get(gca, 'Position'); set(gca, 'Position', [pos(1) pos(2) pos(3) pos(3)]); and then set the colorbar to the same values of the axes. You could use the figure property "ResizeFcn" to update the distance/size of the colorbar to your needs if the figure size changes.

Comment: In my case, I get different values for Matlab and JFrame, as I have shown in the example in question. Using the equal axis is a necessary condition. The main question - why it is impossible to obtain directly the coordinates of the axis box.

Comment: @AlexanderKorovin You do realize that `getAxisComponent` doesn't give you the MATLAB `axes`, right? That refers to the figure dimensions.

Comment: is this still on?

Answer (score 1):

In MATLAB, both a `figure` and an `axes` have a property called `Position`, but it's not the same thing:

`get(hf,'position')` will give you the [position of the figure window on screen](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html#property_Position).
`get(ha,'position')` will return the [position of the axes within the figure window](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_Position).

Therefore, the output of the code

```
hf=figure('units','pixels');
ha=gca(hf);
set(ha,'units','pixels');
hfPos = get(hf,'position')
haPos = get(ha,'position')
```

ans =

```
hfPos = 520   378   560   420
haPos = 73.8000   47.2000  434.0000  342.3000
```

has to be interpreted like this:
[image: this]

However, I have no idea why `get(ha,'position')` returns floating point numbers.

On my system (Win7 Pro, MATLAB R2016a, Java 1.7.0_60-b19) the following code issues a warning:

```
get(gcf,'JavaFrame');
Warning: figure JavaFrame property will be obsoleted in a future release. For more information see the JavaFrame resource on the MathWorks web site.
```

Therefore I would not rely on using it. Instead, I would use the information above to obtain the size and position of the axes plotted in MATLAB.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Did you read my [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39395912/matlab-the-exact-size-and-position-of-the-axis-box-in-the-case-of-axis-equal) and answer on it? The main problem is that the `get(ha,'position')` does not coincide with the real axis box in the case of `axis equal`. About warning, do not worry it is just a warning. We can supress it: `warning('off', 'MATLAB:HandleGraphics:ObsoletedProperty:JavaFrame')`

Comment: A further question is why the `int`s in `hfPos` get cast to doubles after you move or resize the window.